# Sorting is not working if no text in the search field

Tags: bug, ios-app

On the questions tab of the iOS app changing sort order doesn't work immediately if search field is empty.

> [image: empty]

To make it work you need to go to the search field and after tapping on it select <kbd>Search</kbd> button on keyboard:

> [image: keyboard]

If search field on the top is not empty tapping on sort mode on the bottom of the screen (1st picture) change sort order for questions immediately.

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: That's just in the search view though right... So you first have to enter the search and actually search for nothing (on iPhone anyway, not sure about iPad?). I'd say this is possibly intentional as an empty search returns *everything* and so is expensive.

Comment: @Cai I'm not sure that empty search is more expensive than search for instance with one letter "a", because if results is too many only first N is loaded in the list at once. Only after scrolling to the end the next portion will be loaded.

Comment: Yeh fair enough, maybe... still, an empty search is a bit pointless right? You can't do it on the site. It'd probably be better to not show any results at all IMO.

Comment: @Cai while search string is empty I just want to sort ALL of questions according selected mode, but I need to do extra actions. I think these actions could be eliminated. Pretty sure this bug could be fixed by removing something like `if (search.IsEmpty())`.

Comment: Isn't the only sort option you have in search that you don't have on the normal question list "relevance"?

Comment: @Cai maybe in this case "relevance" should work as ["interesting" on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319266/3240681), not sure though.